# Twitter login redirecting to wrong activiy

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

im trying to log in to twitter with this example:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

My problem is that after the log in the browser is done. Its redirecting to my main activity and not to the

activity from where i called the log in method. Because of that i dont get the user

AccessToken from the user.

This is from my manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

My log in method:

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())), TWITER);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

My callback URL

```
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";
```

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
What I did was :

1 - Uninstall sample app from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

2 - Add

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

In the manifest, in the activity you want to get back.

(You might keep the sample app, but change the data android:host="t4jsample" to other string).
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I never integerated with twitter api.

but I think you should start an intent after you get the auth.

```
Intent i = new intent(reditectedActivity.class, thisActivity.this);
startActivity(i);
```

so it's like this

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
        // Check if already logged in
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            Configuration configuration = builder.build();

            TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
            twitter = factory.getInstance();

            try {
                requestToken = twitter
                        .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                this.startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())), TWITER);
Intent i = new intent(reditectedActivity.class, thisActivity.this);
startActivity(i);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // user already logged into twitter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

or in the main activity you can do ..

first define this

```
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = null;
```

then

```
if (!TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL == nul){
Intent i = new intent(mainactivity.this, whereIsTheLogin.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: try the second method